# size of enclosed area in travelling salesman problem optimum

Tags: graph-theory

Can we say the size of enclosed area of optimum solution is greater than enclosed area of any other solution in a TSP problem?

Comment: Where does area come from in a graph?

Comment: Presumably a Euclidean TSP is meant.  But there's no reason to expect area to have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

No. I consider here a Euclidean TSP as suggested by Robert Israel.

Consider the graph with 6 points $A_1=(0,\epsilon),A_2=(\epsilon,0),B=(1,0),C=(1,1),D=(0,1)$ and $E=(0.9,0.9)$.

For small $\epsilon$ a solution for TSP is $A_2BECDA_1$ and its area tends to $1-0.05$ as epsilon tends to $0$.
However $A_1EA_2BCD$ have a bigger area (it tends toward 1 as $\epsilon$ tends to $0$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I apologize for not being clear. Consider a Euclidean TSP on a graph with 4 points A=(1,1), B=(1,3), C=(3,3) and D(3,1). Imagine a point not part of TSP E=(2,2). An optimal solution is ABCDA which has an area of 4. A non-optimal solution is ACBDA which has an area of 2(sum of areas of two triangles AED and BEC).

Comment: Yes you are right. With 4 points I think the TSP solution has the greater area. However for 6 points I gave you a counter example.

Comment: I fail to see how A1BECDA2 is an optimum. Assuming epsilon is less than 0.9, line A1B intersects lines EC and DA2. The solution to your TSP is A2A1DCBE which has a larger area than that of A2EA1BCD.Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the $A_1$ and $A_2$ I edited.